Is it a crime to erase video of a crime you took on your cellphone?
I was watching The Morning Show, and journalist Bradley Jackson (Reese Witherspoon) is in D.C. during the January 6th riots. While inside the capital building, she is recording the events on her cellphone and captures a fight between a police officer and a masked man.  The mask ends up being removed during the fight, revealing it to be her brother.  She deletes the footage to protect him.  There is much made of this in the show that she committed destruction of evidence (in addition to the ethics of it).  But did she actually commit a crime?

usa
See 18 USC 1519:

Whoever knowingly alters, destroys, mutilates, conceals, covers up, falsifies, or makes a false entry in any record, document, or tangible object with the intent to impede, obstruct, or influence the investigation or proper administration of any matter within the jurisdiction of any department or agency of the United States or any case filed under title 1, or in relation to or contemplation of any such matter or case, shall be fined under this title, imprisoned not more than 20 years, or both.

So, in your scenario, was there an intent to impede, obstruct or influence the investigation of any matter within the jurisdiction of any department or agency of the United States?
That would be the main question of fact to determine.
You say:

She deletes the footage to protect him.

Her admitting that publicly may be used as evidence of such intent.
california
In California the statute says:

A person who, knowing that any book, paper, record, instrument in writing, digital image, video recording owned by another, or other matter or thing, is about to be produced in evidence upon a trial, inquiry, or investigation, authorized by law, willfully destroys, erases, or conceals the same, with the intent to prevent it or its content from being produced, is guilty of a misdemeanor.

Similarly, the case would boil down to the question of intent.
Notice that the Federal statute has a very severe punishment (felony with up to 20 years in prison), while the State statute is a misdemeanor (up to 1 year in jail).

ny
The show is based in Manhattan, New York. The NYS law is similar to that in California (but a felony). This sample jury instructions show what the jury needs to consider to determine guilt:

In order for you to find the defendant guilty of this crime, the
People are required to prove from all of the evidence in the case,
beyond a reasonable doubt, each of the following three elements:

That on or about (date), in the county of (specify), the
defendant, (defendant’s name), suppressed physical
evidence by any act of concealment, alteration or
destruction, or by employing force, intimidation or
deception against any person;

That the defendant did so believing that such physical
evidence was about to be produced or used in an
official proceeding [or a prospective official
proceeding]; and

That the defendant did so intending to prevent such
production or use.




One comment asks whether these laws can be applied if the destruction occurs before the investigation started. They can.
The 18 USC 1519 says:

or in relation to or contemplation of any such matter or case

Which clearly provides for a future matter;
The NYS statute says:

was about to be produced or used in an official proceeding [or a prospective official proceeding];

Again, future proceeding is explicitly mentioned;
The CA statute doesn't explicitly mention any contemplated or prospective events, but also doesn't explicitly say that the investigation has to be currently ongoing when the destruction happened.
For the scenario in the show the Federal statute would be most relevant, and maybe NYS (I haven't watched the show, if the deletion occurred back in the studio in Manhattan it could be covered by the NYS law).

Can these laws be applied before there is an actual investigation?
Would it be legal to do a preemptive deletion?

“About to be” seems rather vague. I haven’t seen the show, but assuming she deletes the footage immediately when she sees it’s her brother, any production as evidence would certainly not be imminent; as Magnus says, there isn’t even an investigation yet at that point. I don’t really see why imminence plays into it at all – if I believe something will be introduced as evidence in five years’ time and I destroy it to prevent that, am I any less guilty?

In other TV shows/movies, we often see a business hurriedly shredding documents when they realize the police/FBI are on the way to confiscate them as evidence. But if the business routinely destroys records, would that be considered illegal destruction of evidence?

@Barmar It's not illegal to destroy documents as part of a routine record-retention practice. But the key word is "routine" - if your company normally keeps documents for several years, and then one day out of the blue decides to get rid of anything more than a month old, a jury may certainly infer that this was done for improper reasons.

@Cadence Right. So it's only illegal to destroy evidence that's about to be collected, not to prevent evidence from being created in the first place. An illegal business would normally try not to leave a paper trail that can be used against them.

@Cadence there are requirements to keep specific records at times for up to a decade or even longer

@Trish Yes, and those requirements are in addition to the general duty not to destroy evidence. But many kinds of evidence fall outside of them. For a financial institution, for instance, records of loans taken or credit issued have to be retained for a long time, but internal memos, emails, or financial projections don't - the latter are often sought when investigating banks for improper lending practices. Contrary to Barmar's comment, many businesses that are breaking the law don't have the self-awareness to avoid leaving such a paper trail.

@MagnusWittstrom why not? If she says she did it to protect her brother, that implies she knew he did something wrong and an investigation is imminent.

@Barmar For instance, when Lehman Brothers went bankrupt, investigators combed through over 4 million emails, many of them larded with the kinds of keywords that made them very useful for subsequent trials. None of those would have been covered under required-retention laws and all of them could have been deleted in accordance with normal business practice before the investigation began - but doing so while the investigation was pending would be illegal.

I wonder about two things: 1: Is it an offense to make such recording in the first place? 2: As you cannot be forced to accuse your own family (usually), would there be a exception from the law?


why? 2) There's spousal privilege, but nothing else. You most definitely can be compelled to testify against a sibling.


@U.Windl Protection from being forced to testify against your spouse doesn’t grant you immunity for withholding evidence in an investigation of them. Surrendering evidence is not testimony.

@Cadence If LB had realised how incriminating these e-mails were at some point before the investigation began and had taken steps to delete them, would that have been illegal? (Let’s assume it could actually be established with testimony or otherwise during the investigation that the deletions were not in accordance with normal business practice but done specifically to avoid the e-mails becoming evidence.)

@JanusBahsJacquet I suspect that would depend on the totality of circumstances and how the court interprets such phrases as "in contemplation of" or "prospective official proceeding". If a partner came in and said "we need to delete any evidence of X before the feds charge us", that's bad. If they came in and said "we shouldn't leave all of these emails around, they might be trouble some day" that's more of a gray area.

@JanusBahsJacquet: "am I any less guilty? " I would say yes. It's easier to deduce if you invert it: Option A - you delete something without any existence of a trial or request to produce this as evidence. Option B - you delete this only after you find out that the opposing council (i.e. those who you don't support) has requested this be brought forward as evidence. I would say that B makes you significantly guiltier of intentionally obstructing the trial. Note that the crime is not so much the act of deleting the evidence, but rather the willful obstruction of justice (by deleting it)

@Flater no, the crime is deleting the evidence. Obstruction of Justice is the name of the chapter under which this crime is listed: 18 U.S. Code Chapter 73

"video recording owned by another..." so if it's the property of the one doing the deleting, it's ok?

@littleadv (1) "Whoever knowingly alters, [..]  or makes a false entry in any record, [..]" (2) "A person who, knowing that any [..] thing is about to be produced in evidence" (3) "That the defendant did so believing that such physical evidence was about to be produced or used in an official proceeding" (4) "or in relation to or contemplation of any such matter or case". Awareness is specifically part of the definition. Deletion of something when someone was unaware that this would be evidence does not fit this description, ergo deletion itself is not the transgression.

@Flater intent, you mean. But no, the crime is deletion. Even when the justice is not obstructed, the deletion is a crime if there was an intent. See the conviction of Donald Trump.

@littleadv: You're agreeing with my initial comment. The act of deletion in and of itself is not sufficient, the intention to obstruct is the main transgression here.

@Flater Right, but the intention to obstruct in and of itself is also not sufficient, the act of deletion is necessary.

@littleadv Would you like to back up the claim that intent to destroy evidence without doing so is not a crime? Because attempted crimes are generally still crimes, albeit sometimes to a different punitive degree.

@Flater I made no such claim
